# Amazon SP-API B2B Price Issues

Tags: amazonsellercentral, amazon-selling-partner-api

I am trying to get product pricing and competitive pricing, using the two API calls.

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/product-pricing-api/productPricingV0.md#getpricing

https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/references/product-pricing-api/productPricingV0.md#getcompetitivepricing

I have everything working for normal B2C pricing, based on the below.

[image]
Giving me a response of

```
{
    "payload": [
        {
            "status": "Success",
            "ASIN": "B003X2CREY",
            "Product": {
                "Identifiers": {
                    "MarketplaceASIN": {
                        "MarketplaceId": "A1F83G8C2ARO7P",
                        "ASIN": "B003X2CREY"
                    }
                },
                "Offers": [
                    {
                        "BuyingPrice": {
                            "ListingPrice": {
                                "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
                                "Amount": 169.42
                            },
                            "LandedPrice": {
                                "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
                                "Amount": 169.42
                            },
                            "Shipping": {
                                "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
                                "Amount": 0.00
                            }
                        },
                        "RegularPrice": {
                            "CurrencyCode": "GBP",
                            "Amount": 169.42
                        },
                        "FulfillmentChannel": "MERCHANT",
                        "ItemCondition": "New",
                        "ItemSubCondition": "New",
                        "SellerSKU": "LV429407"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

If I duplicate this exact same call and now add the `OfferType: B2B` it now gives off a unauthorized error.

[image]

If anyone has idea that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have spoken to Amazon Support and they have responded with the following.

> The CustomerType value of "Customer" is not launched for all sellers,
> only certain sellers are part of the beta testing, and other sellers
> will get the access denied issue.

I guess not all of the SP-API are fully developed at present.

Answer (score 0):

do you know /feeds/2021-06-30/feeds  feedType set POST_PRODUCT_PRICING_DATA, then you can make the xml by Price.xsd. if you success, please tell me